# Database design for Buzzfeed like quiz

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

I am creating a tool similar to that of a buzzfeed quiz where users answer questions and have an answer presented that best matches there responses given.

In this case, its a recommendation system whereby the users answer some questions (for example, 'is price a concern?') and then the system will output the accommodation most suited to them (based on a set of pre-defined rules for a property).

The tables I have are:

**QUESTION**: QuestionID, Question

**ANSWERS**: UserID, QuestionID*, Answer_Q1, Answer_Q2, Answer_Q3, Answer_Q4, Answer_Q5,Answer_ Q6, Answer_Q7, Answer_Q8, Answer_Q9, Answer_Q10, Answer_Q11, Answer_Q12, Answer_Q13, Answer_Q14, Answer_Q15

**ACCOM**: AccomID, AccomName, Price, Distance, Type, Ensuite, BillsInc, PostGradOnly, SocialStatus, FamilyFriendly, SingleSex, Parking, AreaStatus, Times_recommended

**RULES**: RuleID, AccomID*, Rule_Q1, Rule_Q2, Rule_Q3, Rule_Q4, Rule_Q5, Rule_Q6, Rule_Q7, Rule_Q8, Rule_Q9, Rule_Q10, Rule_Q11, Rule_Q12, Rule_Q13, Rule_Q14, Rule_Q15

For the rules rules thable, the q1-q15 are for whether or not the rule is relevant for this particular accommodation and question. So for instance, property A may require q5, q9 and q10 to be a 1 for this property to be recommended

I have the problem that I'm not sure how they all fit together. I think this is normalized, but Im struggling to see an ERD in this.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can use this design of your database i this its helpful for you